# BaggingClassifier unexpected keyword argument 'max_depth'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm getting an error for the BaggingClassifier in scikit-learn 0.22.2.post1. I'm using python 3.8.2.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
bag_clf = BaggingClassifier(
                            DecisionTreeClassifier(
                                                    random_state=0,
                                                    criterion='entropy'
                                                    ),
                              n_estimators=100,
                              max_samples=100,
                              max_depth=2,
                              bootstrap=True,
                              random_state=0
                              )
```

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_depth'

If I delete `max_depth=2`, from my code I can create the object. `max_depth=2` is the only argument for which I get the error.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_depth` is an argument of `DecisionTreeClassifier` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)), not of `BaggingClassifier` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html)); you should change the definition to

```
bag_clf = BaggingClassifier(
                            DecisionTreeClassifier( max_depth=2,
                                                    random_state=0,
                                                    criterion='entropy'
                                                    ),
                              n_estimators=100,
                              max_samples=100,
                              bootstrap=True,
                              random_state=0
                              )
```

Comment: oh FFS I can't believe that's what I did!

Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ilmatic9000 you are welcome; as a general rule, you should always check the documentation first, and only post here as a last resort ;)